# GPIO Input activates button in tkinter

Tags: python, button, input, tkinter, gpio

I want either start my timer/count_up_down with the buttons in my GUI or with GPIOs pressed. 
So if GPIO20 is pressed it means the same as pressing the start button in the GUI.
Have anyone an idea where I have to place the checking of the GPIOs. I have tried several things, but nothing worked.

```
import time
from Tkinter import *
from luma.led_matrix.device import max7219
from luma.core.interface.serial import spi, noop
from luma.core.virtual import viewport, sevensegment
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(38, GPIO.IN)

class ClockCount(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):        
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
        serial = spi(port=0, device=0, gpio=noop())
        device = max7219(serial, cascaded=1)
        global seg
        seg = sevensegment(device)
        self._start = 0.0        
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0
        self._running = 0
        self.counterh = 0
        self.countera = 0
        self.segh = "00"
        self.sega = "00"
        self.segt = "00"
        self.timestr = StringVar()
        self.ch = StringVar()
        self.ca = StringVar()
        self._check_gpio()
        self._update_counter()
        #if GPIO.input(40) == TRUE : print "test"

    def _update_counter(self):
        seg.text = str(self.segt)+str(self.segh)+str(self.sega)
        self.ch.set(str(self.counterh))
        self.ca.set(str(self.countera))

    def _check_gpio(self):
        if GPIO.input(40) == TRUE : print "test"
        if GPIO.input(40) == TRUE : self.Stop()

    def _update(self): 

        """ Update the label with elapsed time. """
        self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        self._timer = self.after(50, self._update)
        seg.text = str(self.segt)+str(self.segh)+str(self.sega)
        if GPIO.input(40) == TRUE : print "test"
        if GPIO.input(40) == TRUE : self.Stop()
        if GPIO.input(38) == TRUE : self.Start()   

    def _setTime(self, elap):
        """ Set the time string to Minutes:Seconds:Hundreths """
        minutes = int(elap/60)
        seconds = int(elap - minutes*60.0)
        hseconds = int((elap - minutes*60.0 - seconds)*100)                
        self.timestr.set('%02d:%02d' % (minutes, seconds))
        if len(str(minutes)) < 2 : self.segt = "0" + str(minutes)
        else: self.segt = str(minutes)

    def Start(self):                                                     
        """ Start the stopwatch, ignore if running. """
        if not self._running:            
            self._start = time.time() - self._elapsedtime
            self._update()
            self._running = 1        

    def Stop(self):                                    
        """ Stop the stopwatch, ignore if stopped. """
        if self._running:
            self.after_cancel(self._timer)            
            self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start    
            self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
            self._running = 0

    def Halbzeit(self):                                    
        """ Stop the stopwatch, ignore if stopped. """
        if not self._running: 
            self._start = time.time()         
            self._elapsedtime = 2700.00  
            self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)

    def Reset(self):                                  
        """ Reset the stopwatch. """
        if not self._running:
            self._start = time.time()         
            self._elapsedtime = 0.0    
            self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)

    def counth_up(self):
        self.counterh += 1
        if self.counterh > 99 : self.counterh = 0
        if len(str(self.counterh)) < 2 : self.segh = "0" + str(self.counterh)
        else: self.segh = str(self.counterh)
        self._update_counter()

    def counth_down(self):
        self.counterh -= 1
        if self.counterh < 0 : self.counterh = 0
        if len(str(self.counterh)) < 2 : self.segh = "0" + str(self.counterh)
        else: self.segh = str(self.counterh)
        self._update_counter()

    def counta_up(self):
        self.countera += 1
        if self.countera > 99 : self.countera = 0
        if len(str(self.countera)) < 2 : self.sega = "0" + str(self.countera)
        else: self.sega = str(self.countera)
        self._update_counter()

    def counta_down(self):
        self.countera -= 1
        if self.countera < 0 : self.countera = 0
        if len(str(self.countera)) < 2 : self.sega = "0" + str(self.countera)
        else: self.sega = str(self.countera)
        self._update_counter()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()  
    """root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))"""
    root.geometry('1000x1000')  
    clockcount = ClockCount(root)

    Button(root, font=('Arial',30), width=7, text='Start', command=clockcount.Start).place(x=120, y=200)
    Button(root, font=('Arial',30), width=7, text='Stop', command=clockcount.Stop).place(x=350, y=200)
    Button(root, font=('Arial',30), width=7, text='Halbzeit', command=clockcount.Halbzeit).place(x=580, y=200)  
    Button(root, font=('Arial',30), width=7, text='Reset', command=clockcount.Reset).place(x=810, y=200)
    Button(root, font=('Arial',30), width=7, text='Heim +', command=clockcount.counth_up).place(x=250, y=520)   
    Button(root, font=('Arial',30), width=7, text='Heim -', command=clockcount.counth_down).place(x=250, y=600)
    Button(root, font=('Arial',30), width=7, text='Gast +', command=clockcount.counta_up).place(x=550, y=520)   
    Button(root, font=('Arial',30), width=7, text='Gast -', command=clockcount.counta_down).place(x=550, y=600)
    Button(root, font=('Arial',30), width=7, text='Quit', command=root.destroy).place(x=10, y=10)
    clock_label = Label(root, font="Arial 100 bold", fg="RED", textvariable=clockcount.timestr).place(x=400, y=20)
    counterhome_label = Label(root, font="Arial 100 bold", fg="RED", textvariable=clockcount.ch).place(x=320, y=350)
    counteraway_label = Label(root, font="Arial 100 bold", fg="RED", textvariable=clockcount.ca).place(x=620, y=350)

    #if GPIO.input(40) == TRUE : clockcount.Start()
    #if GPIO.input(40) == TRUE : print "test"

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Many thanks in advance,
br
Robert

Comment: Please try to reduce this code down to a [mcve]. Most of the code seems completely unrelated to the question being asked.

Comment: Read [tkinter-how-to-use-after-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632/tkinter-how-to-use-after-method).